# How to keep <div> align center in this complicated case for floating ad

Tags: html, css, adsense

I know there are lots of people asking the div align center problem. But I tried most solution and it seems won't work in my case. Sorry that I have to ask here. I created the floating ad at my site http://tacfeed.com using the following css,

```
/* Default Stylesheet */
#close {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
color:black;
  background: #fff;
}

#responsive-adsense {
  display: none; 
}

#responsive-adsense{
  display: none;
} 


/*
GENERAL MEDIA QUERY FOR SMALL SCREEN SIZES - COVERS COMMON MOBILE DEVICES, PHONES/TABLETS...
*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

.adcontainer {
  display: none; 
}

#responsive-adsense{
  display: none;
} 

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {

.adcontainer {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
 }

#responsive-adsense {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 padding: 0px !important;
  width: 728px !important;
  display: block !important;
margin:0;
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.adcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;

 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

#responsive-adsense {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 padding: 0px !important;
 width: 728px !important;
 display: block !important; 
margin:0;
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {

.adcontainer {

 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

#responsive-adsense {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 padding: 0px !important;
 width: 468px !important;
 display: block !important; 
margin:0px;
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

.adcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;

 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

#responsive-adsense {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 padding: 0px !important;
 width: 320px !important;
 display: block !important;
margin:0px;
} 

}

/* Here's the css for mobile devices */  
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

.adcontainer {

 width: auto !important; 
 padding: 0px !important;
 height: 50px !important; 
}

#responsive-adsense {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 padding: 0px !important;
 width: 320px !important;
 display: block !important; 
margin:0px;
}

}

/* 
Add your custom styles in this file instead of style.css so it 
is easier to update the theme. Simply copy an existing style 
from style.css to this file, and modify it to your liking. 

When you update your theme, backup this file and re-add it after.
*/

/* Global */
.mystyle {}


/* Tablet - 800px, 768px & 720px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .mystyle {}
}


/* Mobile - 480px & 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {
    .mystyle {}
}


/* Mobile - 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .mystyle {}
}
```

And here is the HTML code at footer, before the end of .

```
<div class="adcontainer" style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)">

<div id="responsive-adsense">
<span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>[X]</span>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- mobileadfor2013 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2658894403753596"
     data-ad-slot="4801520732"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Now, I got two problems. First, the ad align center in portrait mode, but it won't align center if I rotate my iPhone or Android phone to landscape. I tried to use "vertical-align", "margin", "float" and all seems no luck.

Second, the ad does not align to the very bottom of the screen. You can try to visit our site tacfeed.com on mobile. You can see there is at least 1 px left in the bottom area.

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems people don't know this solution to position things to center...you always think the solution needs to be complicated in order to work but you can do this with CSS and it has support on all browsers...

To align verticaly to center a div you only need to add:

```
position: absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
margin: auto;
```

Horizontal:

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin: auto;
```

And now, absolute center:

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin: auto;
```

+Update
**AND, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eexx64n/) to show that/how it works**

++Update
Also, this comes as an update, since now your ad is `position:absolute`, you can add `bottom:0` to it and it will stick to the bottom, no pixels in between.

+++Update
And another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eexx64n/1/) to show the exact way of aligning it to center and make it stick to the bottom